# How to run the code onces the data is retrieved

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, object

doesnt get called.Is there a way to call this code if as soon as an item is added to getItems() array?

Comment: Looks like your `getView()` function is async, and should have a callback or return a promise instead.

Comment: when it doesn't work, how is it broken? any errors in the console?

Comment: @adeneo - that doesn't make sense since it works synchronously in the first code snippet

Comment: no errors :/ and nothing happens in my application. it's empty. but when i settimeout() it calls zoom and works fine

Comment: Can you setup a fiddle? Your question is quite confusing.

Comment: there must be something outside the code you've shown that is asynchronous

Comment: how? :) show me please (using the provided code above) @adeneo

Comment: So what is the error without the timeout? Something is loading and you are not waiting for it. We need more context.

Comment: with settimeout() it works because it retrieves data from an external file. without settimeout it the  o.getAggregation("ooo")[0].getItems() is empty..

Comment: @JaromandaX - you're right, the whole thing is wrapped in the timeout, so there's something outside that timeout that isn't ready ...

Comment: @sarah - so where's the code that gets the file ?

Comment: @JaromandaX yes there is a json file that is retrieved. my settimeout() is inside an onafterrendering fnction

Comment: I'm not familiar with this `onafterrendering` function and how it relates to the retrieval of a json file - perhaps you could show some more code in your question to illustrate what is going on